# Using Lightswitch with my own Domain objects

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm working on an asp.net application. I have a Domain assembly (containing mostly command and queries code), a Domain.Contract assembly ( containing mostly the domain objets), a Repository (called by the Domain) and the Web site.

For some specific backoffice needs, I want to create a Lightswitch application.
I want to use my current domain as a datasource. I added a WCF Ria Service class Library, and in the RiaService.Web project, added a class based on DomainService, with one query method. Nothing more (no entities, since they are in my Domain.Contract assembly)

When in Lightswitch, I add the RiaService.Web assembly as a DataSource, in the Select Data Source Objects, it tells me :
"The selected WCF RIA Service does not contain any entity definitions. Once the service is modified, you will need to refresh the data source."

And now, I'm stuck : in every sample I can find, the entities are in the RiaService.Web assembly, but i don't want to recreate the objects I already made.

Thanks :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have at least one method that does not take parameters that returns the collection type. You don't have to use it, but you have to have it.

Comment: And also mark it as    [Query(IsDefault = true)]


Thanks a lot !

 Now, I'm getting the "The Entity  in DomainService does not have a key defined", but I think I understand this one.